# modify an xarray column with a calculation

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

This seems like it should be pretty straight forward, but perhaps my inexperience with arrays is making it difficult for me.  I have an xarray
[image]

what i am trying to do is multiply the band column by something along the lines of

```
ds[:, 0] = (ds[:, 0] - xmin) / (xmax - xmin)
```

where

```
xmin is -0.21
xmax is 0.3
```

the line above does not seem to work as expected. it seems to modify the nodata values. I also tried

```
 ds2 = ds.where(ds.band > -10000.0)
```

then ran the line, with different but still incorrect results.

the xmin and xmax are not related to the XY data, the raster that I am reading into an array has XYZ data,  what I am trying to do is normalize the Z(elevation) column, which I think is displayed as "band" in the image. The xmin and xmax are actually the minimum and maximum Z value of several rasters/arrays that I will be comparing.

So I don't want to modify the XY only the Z. After words, I will be re-exporting the array back into a raster

So for the entire column adjust each value with the above formula

I'm sure this is a very easy task, but i can not figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 3d `DataArray`, but the `band` dimension is only 1, so you basically have a 2d array. You can use `ds.squeeze()` to drop the dimension if you don’t need / want it.

When you say

> what i am trying to do is multiply the band column

do you mean applying the multiplication to the whole array (so to each pixel)?

In that case, you can do:

```py
xmin = -0.21
xmax = 0.3

ds_scaled = (ds - xmin) / (xmax - xmin)
```

Since it looks like you want to scale/normalize the data, you can also use `xmin` and `xmax` derived from the data:

```py
# over full array
xmin = ds.min()
xmax = ds.max()

ds_scaled = (ds - xmin) / (xmax - xmin)
```

or just over as specific dimension

```py
# over y dimension
xmin = ds.min(‘y’)
xmax = ds.max(‘y’)

ds_scaled = (ds - xmin) / (xmax - xmin)
```

Comment: the xmin xmax is misleading i suppose. what i have are several rasters that I am trying to normalize the elevation column. the xmin xmax are not related to the XY

Comment: @Messak that’s basically what the 2nd example does; you take the min and max over the whole 2d array (containing your elevation values if I understand correctly) and normalize the data